# Wordpress bootstrap navbar css

Tags: css

I have spent many hours trying to extend the color in the navbar! Would any one know the css to add ? It's a bought theme but the support is shocking :(

Here is the url [homepage](http://aussteve.com/)

and what I am trying to do extend background of navbar

[image]

Comment: Put menu labels like gallery , contact us etc in a span and add the following style

#topnav > li > a > span{
    background-color:#fff;
}

Comment: Consider using freelancing website to get the task done for you, because StackOverflow does not provide free programming force. If you have specific questions on how to do something, ask those.

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried so far, and what errors/issues have you faced? StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Ideally provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)